# Annotation tool to annotate a cross lingual corpus

Tags: annotation

I need an annotation tool to annotate a cross lingual corpus at sentence level, matching sentences from two documents if they are in a paraphrase relationship. Can someone please help me find a tool to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Clark, an XML based corpous annotation tool, for annotating your corpora. The link is [here](http://www.bultreebank.org/clark/).

Other tools are:

- [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk)

  GATE is a modular system for the linguistic processing of texts. It comprises an architecture, library framework and graphical development environment. Plugins can be used to build an application for a particular annotation task. GATE is freely available under GNU Library General Public License (LGPL 2.0) and can be downloaded after a registration. It is implemented in Java, and thus available for all major platforms.
- [Alembic Workbench Project](http://%20Alembic%20Workbench%20Project)

  Tool for manual and automatic annotation of text corpora. Automatic annotation is achieved by a mixed approach: heuristics for information extraction can be manually composed or automatically inducted. Available free of charge.
- [PALinkA: A Discourse Annotation Tool](http://clg.wlv.ac.uk/projects/PALinkA/)

  An annotation program which allows a wide range of annotations. At present it has been used to annotate texts for anaphora resolution, centering, summarisation and marking certain features in texts.
- [Annotate](http://An%20annotation%20program%20which%20allows%20a%20wide%20range%20of%20annotations.%20At%20present%20it%20has%20been%20used%20to%20annotate%20texts%20for%20anaphora%20resolution,%20centering,%20summarisation%20and%20marking%20certain%20features%20in%20texts.)

  Annotate is a tool for efficient semi-automatic annotation of corpus data. It facilitates the generation of context-free structures and additionally allows crossing edges.
- [MMAX](http://mmax.eml-research.de/)

  A tool for multi-modal annotation in XML

---

You can also read about corpus annotation below:

[1] : http://nlp.ipipan.waw.pl/~adamp/Papers/2009-ltc-tei/ltc-030-przepiorkowski.pdf

[2] : http://www.birmingham.ac.uk/documents/college-artslaw/corpus/conference-archives/2007/187Paper.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The task you are looking for is called *Alignment* and the most popular tool for it is [hunalign](http://mokk.bme.hu/resources/hunalign/).